# How to insert data to bootstrap table with some code?

Tags: php, mysqli, html-table, bootstrap-4

Having an issue with inserting data to a bootstrap table. Some part of the code is too complicated to insert into  the table correctly!

What I have already done is tried to insert that data to the table many ways, but nothing working so far!

This is original bootstrap table what I want it looks like!

```
    echo '<div class="example-wrap">
            <p>Filmsground Users</p>
            <div class="example table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>                        
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Username</th>
                    <th>Modules Access</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Teagan</td>
                    <td>
                      <span class="label label-danger">admin</span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-flat btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                    data-original-title="Edit">
                    <i class="icon wb-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>';
```

And the code what needs to be inserted to bootstrap table!

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC");
    while ($results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo '<p><strong><a href="?inav=useredit&id='.$results['id'].'">'.$results['username'].'</a></strong>: ';
        if ($results['membertype'] == 'admin')
        {
            echo 'Admin users have access to everything.';
        }
        else
        {
        $user = $results['username'];
        $query_prev = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_prevs WHERE username='".$user."'");
            while ($prevs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_prev))
            {
                $pattern = '/\[module\](.*?)\[\/module\]/is';
                $replace = '$1 ';
                $module_name = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $prevs['prevs']);

                echo $module_name;
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP can go hand in hand with html. You can use this type of way:

```
 <?php
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)
   {  
 while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
   {
  ?>
   <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr >
   <td align="center"><?php echo $row4['articleID'];?>
    </td>
    <td  align="center"><?php echo $row4['articleName'];?>
    </td >
     <td align="center"><?php echo  $sordCodeFO; ?>
     </td>
     <td align="center"><?php echo $row4['color'];?>
     </td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row4['style'];?>
    </td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row4['size'];?>
   </td>
    <td align="center"><?php echo $row4['quantity'];?>
    </td></tr></tbody>
  <?php
    }
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggest, but want use the way how it is!